# jQuery.each() -- how does jQuery know whether argument is index, key, value or object?

Tags: jquery

Say something like this:

```
$.each(json_object_or_array, function(arg1, arg2) {

      //do something
});
```

I've seen cases where `arg1` , `arg2` are `i` or `index` or `key` or `val` or `value` or `obj` or even random names that are implicitly referring to one of these. For example, I've seen `function(key, val)` also presented as `function(name, val)`. How does jQuery know that `name` here is referring to `key`?

How does jQuery know what we're referring to?

Comment: Because its the first argument passed to the function. First is key, second is value.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @Jake Thanks for response. But how does it know I wasn't trying to do `function(i, val)`?

Comment: @user1883050 It doesn't matter, as `a[i]` will return the value at the key `i`, no matter if `i` is an index in an array or a property name in an object.

Comment: @user1883050 If it is `Array` then it will be `index` `value` , If it will be `object` then it has `key` `value`. Based on `$.each(object/Array)`. `$.each` is a **generic iterator function**.

Comment: @user1883050 Please check my and jai's answer. You will get better understanding how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by knowing English. What variable names you use is completely arbitrary - the parameter names are only pertinent within the function. The index (or i, or key) is the first argument; the value (or obj, or val) is the second.

EDIT: If you are asking how `jQuery.each` knows whether it should iterate as if the collection was an array or as if it was an object - it tries to detect it from the collection itself. Sometimes it missed, especially in older versions of jQuery.

```js
var weird = {
  length: 2,
  width: 7,
  breadth: 8
};

$.each(weird, function(k, v) {
  console.log(k, v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here, it thinks we are dealing with an array because it has `length`, so it starts counting indices. Newer jQuery will do it correctly, and display the object's attributes:

```js
var weird = {
  length: 2,
  width: 7,
  breadth: 8
};

$.each(weird, function(k, v) {
  console.log(k, v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But index and key mean different things right? E.g., in `{apple:"red", pear:"green"}`, the indexes are 1 and 2, and the keys are apple and pear. Correct?

Comment: There is no `1` or `2` in `{apple:"red", pear:"green"}`. Objects have key-value pairs (or attribute name-value pairs), arrays have values at indices. Indices serve the same purpose in arrays as keys in objects. In fact, arrays in JavaScript are a special kind of object, which is optimised for attributes with names `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`... and has a magic `"length"` attribute. For most intents and purposes, array indices in JS *are* keys. `["foo", "bar"]["1"] == "bar"`, and `Object.keys(["foo", "bar"]) == ["0", "1"]`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. (I just want to add for my own future reference that I shouldn't have commented earlier that "the indexes are 1 and 2" ... I meant to write "the indexes are 0 and 1" because javascript follows zero-based array indexing).

Comment: Another question could be: why did JQuery devs choose to use `(index, val)` for `$.each`, and `(val, index)` for `$.map` or `$.grep`...

Comment: @X.L.Ant: I want to ask the same question. When I am in a good mood. Other times, I just want to punch someone. :P (not really, but it is very aggravating.)

Answer (score 2):

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is a **generic iterator function**.

If it is `Array` then it will be `index` `value` , If it will be `object` then it has `key` `value`. Based on `$.each(object/Array)`.

You can check type based on

```
jQuery.type( new Array() ) === "array" or  


jQuery.type( new Object() ) === "object"
```

jQuery internally check [type](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) and basied on that whole thing works.

Answer (score 1):

Although answer is been chosen but i want to explain my thoughts:

The below snippet is taken from jQuery library here you can see what it does internally. You can see the if conditions are there where it checks for the object to be an `Array` or `Object`.

It internally creates a loop if passed element is an Array like object then use standard for loop for iterations:

```
for(;;){}
```

if object then use for....in loop:

```
for(var key in object){}
```

so this snippet shows the usage:

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var value,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj ); // <---this checks the passed obj is [] || {}

    if ( args ) {
        if ( isArray ) { // <----------------------if [] then use standard for loop
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else { // <------------------------------if {} then use for..in loop 
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    ........
},
```

here is the `isArrayLike()` method:

```
function isArraylike( obj ) {

    // Support: iOS 8.2 (not reproducible in simulator)
    // `in` check used to prevent JIT error (gh-2145)
    // hasOwn isn't used here due to false negatives
    // regarding Nodelist length in IE
    var length = "length" in obj && obj.length,
        type = jQuery.type( obj );

    if ( type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length ) {
        return true;
    }

    return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
        typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
}
```

Comment: You are right. Can you show `isArraylike` function.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi added from jQuery src.

Comment: thanks Ok it is checking with `type` as i mentioned.

Comment: Now we are going with jQuery development structure :)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi correct but i just want to show the actual code what is happening when if the passed element is `[] || {}`. Usage of two different for loops.

Comment: A generic development. We stucked in ques/answer about usage and issues. Its more think about how it works :)